# /var file system gets full quickly

Tags: linux, var

/var file system gets full quickly. Even the inodes' usage reaches 100%. We have to clear the logs regularly. We are not able to ssh also because of this. We have do a hard reboot eventually. We are not able to identify the exact root cause for the same. Kindly help us out in pin pointing the exact cause and resolving the issue.

What is the proper way to prevent /var from filling the disk space on a server with limited storage space?

Comment: Your question includes almost no useful information. How big the partition? How quickly does it fill? Do you see files appear? If so, what are there names, how big are they, what's in them? What tools have you used to look at the usage? What did they tell you?

Comment: Also, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85184/var-partition-gets-full-whats-the-solution var-partition-gets-full-whats-the-solution

Answer (score 3):

`/var` is the location where most of the data is stored by applications. This includes *log files*, *libraries* or even binary *data* for applications like *MySQL* or *MongoDB*.

Coming to your problem, as you have mentioned clearing logs frequently, you need to monitor what writes to `/var/log` the most and set appropriate *logrotate* policy for the same.

To find the top 10 directories (inside `/var`) by disk usage:

```
sudo du -h /var | sort -hr | head -n10
```

To find the top 10 files (inside `/var/log`) by disk usage

```
sudo find /var/log -maxdepth 2 ! -path . -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -rn -k1  | head
```

---

What is the disk size available to the machine?

How frequently does it get full?

What is the output of the above two commands?

Comment: my problem was with yum.pid not getting created because of cache being full. thanks for predicting the scenario. Last I cleaned the /var and then ssh wasn't working (and it shouldn't have right.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the pipe on `head -n10` is only going to print out the first 10 directory entries in `/var`. If you have more than 10 directories, they are not being reported on. Secondly, `du -h` is not quite the best tool to use here as it is reporting duplicated allocation because child directories are being reported on.

Try this instead to get a better idea on allocation of all first level directories under `/var`:

```
# find /var -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -smh '{}' \;

21G     /var
18G     /var/lib
4.0K    /var/local
384K    /var/www
86M     /var/cache
3.3G    /var/log
12K     /var/mail
16K     /var/lost+found
7.8M    /var/backups
840K    /var/spool
4.0K    /var/tmp
4.0K    /var/opt
```

If you need to drill down into one of those top levels, to report allocation under the parent, simply add the sub directory to the original command. I can easily see `elasticsearch` is the culprit behind 18G of allocation within `/var` on my system:

```
# find /var/lib -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -smh '{}' \;
18G     /var/lib
...
8.0K    /var/lib/vim
18G     /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

@fpmurphy suggest the `yum` directory may be involved with your problem. To extrapolate on that, whenever you work with `yum` all the packages which are downloaded to update the system are retained under `/var/cache/yum` by default. You may want to check the contents of the file `/etc/yum.conf` and check for the [`keepcache` setting](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html). What you post suggests that `keepcache` has a value of `1`.

If `/var/cache/yum` is indeed filling up, you may be able to run`yum clean all` to fix things for now. [There is evidence](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/974373) this command may not work as advertised however so [take heed](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=263674). I would suggest allocating more space to `/var` if possible.